# Set initial value in a table with a dropdown on each row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a table with a list of event registrations for a particular customer. I have dropdowns in each row that allow changing the customer's registration status for the given event in the row. However, their current status isn't being set in the list; the first item is selected in every list.

ViewModel:

```
public class EditRegistrationViewModel
{
    public int SiteMemberId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<EditParticipantViewModel> Participants { get; set; }
}

public class EditParticipantViewModel
{
    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Event ID")]
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public string StartDateTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Participation Status")]
    public int SelectedParticipationStatus { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> ParticipationStatusList { get; set; }
}
```

View (just the C# for loop block)

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Participants.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Participants[i].ParticipantId)
        <td class="text-right">@Model.Participants[i].EventId</td>
        <td>@Model.Participants[i].Name</td>
        <td>@Model.Participants[i].StartDateTime</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(
            m => m.Participants[i].SelectedParticipationStatus,
            Model.Participants[i].ParticipationStatusList,
            new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Controller (populating the initial value, but the dropdown isn't set to it)

```
foreach (var i in participantQuery)
{
    EditParticipantViewModel theItem = new EditParticipantViewModel()
    {
        ParticipationStatusList = tblEnum.GetSelectListForConstraintId(CRConstants.PARTICIPATION_STATUS_CONSTRAINT_ID),
        ParticipantId = i.a.aID,
        EventId = i.c.aID,
        Name = i.c.tName,
        SelectedParticipationStatus = i.b.nParticipationStatus ?? 0
    };
    DateTime? startDate = i.d.GetStartDateTime();
    theItem.StartDateTime = startDate.HasValue ? startDate.Value.ToString() : "-";
    theViewModel.Participants.Add(theItem);
}
```

Here's the code that gets the select list:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetSelectListForConstraintId(int constraintId)
{
    CCSContext db = new CCSContext();
    List<SelectListItem> theList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    List<tblEnum> enumList = db.Enum.Where(x=>x.nConstraintID == constraintId).OrderBy(x=>x.nOrder).ToList();
    foreach (var i in enumList)
    {
        SelectListItem theItem = new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = i.tDisplayName,
            Value = i.nIndex.ToString()
        };
        theList.Add(theItem);
    }
    return theList;
}
```

Comment: As long as there's value in `SelectedParticipationStatus`, this should work.Could you post `GetSelectListForConstraintId` as well?

Comment: @adiga I've added the method. Essentially I just loop through the list of statuses in the database, make a selectlistitem out of each one, and return the list.

Comment: @adiga Yeah, that's what's confusing me in particular, as I have other places in my code that does this just fine, just not a list where each row has a dropdown.

Comment: I just rememebred there is an issue with looping. Try `@Html.DropDownListFor(
            m => m.Participants[i].SelectedParticipationStatus,
            new SelectList(Model.Participants[i].ParticipationStatusList, "Value","Text", Model.Participants[i].SelectedParticipationStatus ),
            new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: @adiga Same result. I'm going to try this answer below too.

Comment: updated the comment. Forgot to add the `selectedValue` param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have to use the html helper methods inside a loop to render the input elements and you would like model binding to work flawlessly, It is better to use **EditorTemplates**. With that you do not need to write a lot of code looping/manipulating the input element names etc.

Simply create a new folder called `EditorTemplates` under `~\Views\Shared\`  or `~\Views\YourControllerName` and create a view with the same name as of the class name you use as the type of the collection item ( `EditParticipantViewModel.cshtml`)

Have the below code there to render each row

```
@model EditParticipantViewModel
<tr>
    <td class="text-right">@Model.EventId @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ParticipantId)</td>
    <td>@Model.Name</td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
                        m => m.SelectedParticipationStatus,
                        Model.ParticipationStatusList, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now in the main view which is strongly typed to `EditRegistrationViewModel`, call the `Html.EditorFor` helper method

```
@model EditRegistrationViewModel
<h2>Form using Editor template</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
  <table>
    @Html.EditorFor(f=>f.Participants)
  </table>
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

This will render the table rows for each items in `Participants` collection of your view model and for each row, the desired option will be pre selected (assuming you are setting the correct `SelectedParticipationStatus` property value for each item in the GET action and it matches with one of the option's `value` attribute value.)

Model binding will also work when you submit the form.

Comment: That does it. And now it looks like I get to learn more about EditorTemplates.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with binding `DropDownListFor` in a loop. You can either use `EditorTemplates` or you can try something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
        m => m.Participants[i].SelectedParticipationStatus,
        new SelectList(Model.Participants[i].ParticipationStatusList, "Value","Text", 
           Model.Participants[i].SelectedParticipationStatus),
        new { @class = "form-control" })
```